# Adding rows to table layout in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Im having trouble adding a row to my simple array list in kotlin... im new with android studio so code might not be in the best shape

xml file:

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.InventoryFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Inventory"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/InventoryTextView"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="478dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableInventory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="*">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tbrow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/t1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Device Name" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/t2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Floor" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/t3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Code" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/t4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Priority" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/t5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Maintenance Scheduele" />


            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="530dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AddNewMachineInventory"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#95E6F1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
            android:text="Add Machine"
            />
</LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>'
```

and the fragment looks like this:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.grad_project_2020.R
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_inventory.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_inventory_add_dialog.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_task_f_t_nfragment.*


class InventoryFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var alertDialog: AlertDialog

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        var View: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inventory, container, false)
        return View
    }

    var data = arrayListOf<String>()
    val data1 = arrayListOf<String>()
    val data2 = arrayListOf<String>()
    val data3 = arrayListOf<String>()
    val data4 = arrayListOf<String>()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        var table: TableLayout = this.requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.tableInventory)
        var row: TableRow = TableRow(this.requireActivity())

        var i:Int = 0;
        var x:Int = 1;

        AddNewMachineInventory.setOnClickListener {
            val inflater: LayoutInflater = this.getLayoutInflater()
            val dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inventory_add_dialog, null)
            val AddInventoryCancel: Button = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.AddInventoryCancel)
            val AddInventoryAdd: Button = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.AddInventoryAdd)

            AddInventoryCancel.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                (alertDialog).dismiss()
            }
            AddInventoryAdd.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                var ed1 = dialogView.AddInventoryName.text.toString()
                var ed2 = dialogView.AddInventoryLocation.text.toString()
                var ed3 = dialogView.AddInventoryCode.text.toString()
                var ed4 = dialogView.AddInventoryPriority.text.toString()
                var ed5 = dialogView.AddInventorySchedule.text.toString()

                data.add(ed1)
                data1.add(ed2)
                data2.add(ed3)
                data3.add(ed4)
                data4.add(ed5)

                val t1: TextView = TextView(requireActivity())
                val t2: TextView = TextView(requireActivity())
                val t3: TextView = TextView(requireActivity())
                val t4: TextView = TextView(requireActivity())
                val t5: TextView = TextView(requireActivity())

                for (i in data.indices){
                    var machine = data.get(i)
                    var location = data1.get(i)
                    var code = data2.get(i)
                    var priority = data3.get(i)
                    var schedule = data4.get(i)

                    t1.setText(machine)
                    t2.setText(location)
                    t3.setText(code)
                    t4.setText(priority)
                    t5.setText(schedule)

                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("$i")
                        .child("Name").setValue(ed1)
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("$i")
                        .child("Location").setValue(ed2)
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("$i")
                        .child("Code").setValue(ed3)
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("$i")
                        .child("Priority").setValue(ed4)
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("$i")
                        .child("Schedule").setValue(ed5)

                    row.addView(t1)
                    row.addView(t2)
                    row.addView(t3)
                    row.addView(t4)
                    row.addView(t5)

                    table.addView(row)

                }


                (alertDialog).dismiss()
            }
            val dialogBuilder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            dialogBuilder.setOnDismissListener(object : DialogInterface.OnDismissListener {
                override fun onDismiss(arg0: DialogInterface) {
                }
            })
            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView)
            alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show()
        }

    }
}
```

the error i get is this

The specified child already has a parent. You must call `removeView()` on the child's parent first.
and its about the      `table.addView(row)`

i saw some answers online to why this happens...yet the same exact code is in the docs and online tutorials
any ideas ?

Stack trace for the error:

```
07/20 21:11:44: Launching 'app' on Pixel 3a API 30.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.grad_project_2020/com.example.grad_project_2020.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 12781 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/ad_project_202: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/ad_project_202: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf10561b0, tid 12802
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xd8292290: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd8292290: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc1d01690) (first time)
I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf1054230, tid 12802
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fc3e0000 size 0x2000
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2008 bytes, containing 1 windows, 10 views
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 6616 bytes, containing 2 windows, 46 views
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10152; state: ENABLED
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 7036 bytes, containing 2 windows, 51 views
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.grad_project_2020, PID: 12781
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5162)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4991)
        at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:427)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4931)
        at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:409)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4904)
        at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:400)
        at com.example.grad_project_2020.fragments.InventoryFragment$onViewCreated$1$2.onClick(InventoryFragment.kt:106)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28296)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: To me problem appears to be caused by FOR loop. you are creating row object outside and then reusing it for second row which is incorrect. move the row creation object to inside for loop along with creation of other textview objects

Comment: @gujralam i tried doing that as well.. would gave me the same exact error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the changes, and to provide the complete stack trace for the new code.

Comment: @MikeM. Oh sorry i didnt realize i should do that... im new to this whole coding thing xD

Comment: Question. Should I always post the stack trace? and should it be the full one and not just teh error trace ?

Comment: You're still only creating one `TableRow`. gujralam was saying to move the `var row: TableRow = TableRow(this.requireActivity())` line. However, I'm not sure that you need that `for` loop at all. Aren't you only adding one row at a time?

Comment: Yes yes i am adding 1 row at a time (supposedly)
the for loop is just to store the data of the array list + save the data in multiple children on firebase

Comment: OK, you still need to create a new `TableRow` each time, so the `var row: TableRow = ...` line should be in the `AddInventoryAdd.setOnClickListener {}` block. However, you don't need the `for` loop there, because you don't want to add all of the previous items again; you just want to add the current new one, yeah? It looks like you can just remove `for (i in data.indices){` line, and its closing `}`, 'cause the loop body is alreade set up to add a whole row.

Comment: It depends on your situation. If you're only ever going to have a few rows, the `TableLayout` might be simplest. If you're going to have a large, variable number of items, then a `RecyclerView` might be preferable.

Comment: OMG YES!! Im laughing at myself right now :D such a silly mistake!
Thank you so much!

Comment: Just for the future.. as im new to all this
should I have phrased anything better? or done something differently? (on the post i mean)
im just asking to learn the proper etiquette for this website

Comment: Well, if you want the honest, strict assessment, it's not bad, but there are a few things that might have attracted that downvote, if that's what you're wondering about. Things that aren't directly relevant to the issue don't need to be in the question; e.g., we don't need to know that you're new to Android. Aside from that, there's more code and XML given than is needed. Users are asked to put together a [mcve] to demonstrate the issue, and simply doing that will often make the solution self-evident. As far as the stack trace, it's generally preferable to just include the whole thing...

Comment: ...from the start. Sometimes, only the Exception message is necessary, but other times, we need to follow the trace to see exactly how things are executing. Unless you're already quite familiar with Android debugging, it's hard to know which is sufficient, so posting the whole thing to begin with can save some time. Lastly, this is a rather common Exception, with many questions here already that cover it, so some users will downvote just because of that. If you are posting about a common issue, it's best to make it clear that you have researched, and to provide links and snippets to show it.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike M. spotted the silly mistake.
just moved the var row: TableRow = TableRow() to inside the AddInventoryAdd.setOnClickListener {} to create a new row each click!